# Concurrently powering ten micro DC motors in a circuit

Tags: circuit-design, dc-motor

I have built a sort of small raspi controlled remote car with 10 tires using regular drone motors such as [these ones](https://www.amazon.de/ViaGasaFamido-RPM-50000-Hohlschale-Coreless-Quadcopter/dp/B07Z3XBPDS/ref=sr_1_5?dchild=1&keywords=3v%20drone%20motor&qid=1628187888&sr=8-5) and am using a raspberry pi and six [DRV8833 motor drivers](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8833.pdf?ts=1628136664305&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) to control them. The power source is a [60 W AC adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B083GG2H6R) that can be downregulated to 3.5 V.
Initially the circuit was barely able to run two motors concurrently with the provided power source alone. The LEDs of the DRV8833 all fluctuated and went black whenever more than two motors were running.

I connected ten 470 mF 35 V capacitors to the circuit (in parallel, the positive side connected to the v+ wire and the negative one to ground) and now I am able to run almost six of those motors at the same time. However, these capacitors are quite large and I don't want to add another ten or fifteen just to be able to get this device running the way it's supposed to be.

Right now the car is turned upside down and the motors are running without any resistance apart from the force required to get the motors to run.

The current limit for the DRV8833 is 2 A, I am using two of those modules with each having two motors connected to them.

Here is what the setup roughly looks like:

[image]

Is there a better way to deal with the sudden burst of required current when firing up all motors at once? Right now I am using the capacitors as some sort of battery, is there something else that is more efficient that I could use in place of that?

Would maybe something like [this](http://aliexpress.com/item/32959425298.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.315267258gBKX7&algo_pvid=d905b8a1-4e33-4d27-862d-0200c6974045&algo_exp_id=d905b8a1-4e33-4d27-862d-0200c6974045-3&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000024079713768%22%7D) work for my purpose, if I downregulated the voltage from 30 V to 3 V using resistors?

Comment: if you use resistors to lower the voltage, then the output voltage will no longer be regulated, unless the load current never changes

Comment: jsotola is there an alternative to this? I was not able to find a PSU specifically designed to withstand these types of spikes in voltage that operate on a voltage of 3.5V

Comment: what amount of gear reduction are you using?

Comment: (1) The root cause of trouble is that all motors start at the same time, each with a big rush of current, usually several times of the steady current. (3) There are basically 2 solutions, software and hardware. (4) Using software, you can let Rpi to start the motors sequentially, one after another, with a delay of say, 10ms. (5) Or if you wish all motors start at the same time, you can let Rpi start them all at a very low speed, by setting PCM duty cycle, at 20% or even less.  / to continue, ...

Comment: (6) For hardware approach, you can get those cheap motor driver modules with a built in poly fuse, which limits the starting current in rush.

Comment: You haven't told us how you are gearing the motors down to drive the wheels. (If they are directly driven, this is an altogether hopeless case until you learn the relationship between voltage and speed, and torque and current, which will reveal why gearing (translate between speed and torque) is universally used) Also, do you really mean 350mF, = 350,000 uF? If so, yes that's quite large. If you meant 350uF that's pretty small, and larger caps will help some)

Comment: @tlfong01 Delaying (sequencing) startup will likely only solve the problem until the car is turned right side up. Then, the first motors will simply remain in stall until the rest are turned on... Soft starting them all, might work, given adequate gearing.

Comment: @user_1818839,  well, my 4WD uses 4 gear motors with encoder (TM310, 12V,1:90, 12pps).  My Rpi Pico in real time, monitors the 4 encoder interrupt signals every 10ms.

Comment: And the 4 motors at 12V 1kHz PWM 50% duty cycle no load, generates encoder pulses around 300 pulses per 10ms. So stall response time should be OK. Ref: https://penzu.com/p/0ba73c7b.

Comment: @tlfong01 I would try to use the hardware approach, but I was unable to find a motor driver with those properties. I looked on aliexpress mainly. It would also need to be able to be connected to a power outlet and supply enough amperage to support 10+ 3v dc motors. Is there a good way to search for a psu like that using specific keywords?

Comment: This is the motor driver with a polyfses: https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a1z1r.7974869.0.0.6d0d3ad47ewodh&id=594048616008. Actually you can easily add your own polyfust in series with you motor driver. Mine is just handy with the polyfuse built in.

Comment: I skimmed your motor spec and found it only using 150mA. So 150mA x 10 = 1.5A and you can easily find lipo batteries with that sort of capacity.